# MsgBox for a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a code that displays a MsgBox if contents in cells of column G are not equal to 0. Code works with just one cell but not with the full range (G20:G100). 
can you please help.
thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G20:G100").Value <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not equal to 0", vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That wont work.  As the range will be an array, you need to use `worksheetfunction.countif`

Comment: I'm unclear on how you would deal with empty cell which register as both ISNUMBER and equal to `""`.

Comment: @ADRSAL  did you get to test any of the answers you got ? any feedback ?

Comment: Yes I did. basically the main function of column G is like a data validation. If the answer of E-F=0, then it's correct, if not 0, then the msg comes up. what I've noticed is that every time I input a value in column E, a mismatch error comes up. is there a way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In Range("G20:G100")
        If myCell <> 0 Then
            MsgBox myCell.Address & " is not equal to 0", vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next myCell        
End Sub
```

It checks every cell in the range. For the first cell it finds with a different value than 0, it gives a `MsgBox` with its address and it exits.

You can make the `MsgBox` a bit more informative, showing the current value of the cell like this:

```
MsgBox myCell.Address & " is " & myCell.Text, vbOKOnly
```

If you remove the `Exit Sub` it will show different `MsgBox`-es for each cell that is different than `0`.

Comment: Maybe add a check first that there are non-zero values to save looping?

Comment: Also, might be worth dynamically getting the last used row rather than a static range

Comment: @SJR - yup, it will be faster.

Comment: @Zac - it depends from the intentions of the OP, but it is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The code below is a little longer, but you will get the result in 1 summary `MsgBox` with a list of all cells in the `Range("G20:G" &LastRow)` which are `<>0`.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim myCell As Range, LastRow As Long
    Dim MsgString As String

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in Column G
    ' making sure there is at least 1 cell with data in it below "G20"
    If LastRow < 20 Then
        MsgBox "Your range from G20 and below is empty", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each myCell In Range("G20:G" & LastRow)
        If myCell.Value <> 0 Then
            If MsgString <> "" Then  ' not first cell which is <> 0
                MsgString = MsgString & vbCr & myCell.Address
            Else
                MsgString = myCell.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell

    MsgBox "The following cells are not equal to 0 :" & vbCr & MsgString, vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

**Note**: cell which are `Empty` do not enter the criteria of `<>0`, so if you want also to find empty cells as well, the code will need some slight modifications.