# Calling a macro from another

Tags: excel, vba

I running a macro that pops up a message if the user inputs a value in column E having column D empty. therefore the user has to input value in D and then in E. once the user inputs a value in D, by Vlookup formula the sheet will display a number in column F. 
The second macro should then check if value of column F is not equal to value input in column E, if not equal popup a message.
First part is working but not the second. any idea please. thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Cells(Target.Row, 5).Address And Target.Value <> "" And Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "" Then

       MsgBox "Input value in column D"
       Cells(Target.Row, 4).Select
       Target.Clear        
    End If        
Call Macro2

End Sub

Sub Macro2()

   If Target.Address = Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 5).Address And Target.Value <> "" And Target.Value <> Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 6).Value Then
    MsgBox "E and F don't match"

   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second one is the problem, then pass the `Target` to it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False                    '<--- Consider removing this line
    If Target.Address = Cells(Target.Row, 5).Address _
       And Target.Value <> "" _
       And Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = "" Then

        MsgBox "Input value in column D"
        Cells(Target.Row, 4).Select
        Target.Clear    
    End If    

    Macro2 Target        
    Application.EnableEvents = True                      '<--- Consider removing this line
End Sub

Sub Macro2(Target As Range)

    If IsError(Target) Then
        MsgBox Target.Address & "is an error!"
    ElseIf IsError(Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 6)) Then
        MsgBox Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 6).Address & " is an error!"
    ElseIf Target.Address = Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 5).Address _
           And Target.Value <> "" _
           And Target.Value <> Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 6).Value Then
        MsgBox "E and F don't match"
    End If

End Sub
```

However, it could be that `Target.Clear` is making a loop within the `Worksheet_Change`, because it changes the worksheet once again. Depending on whether this is ok or not ok, you may consider writing `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the start or at the end of the `Sub`.

Comment: I'm getting an error '13" type mismatch for part  If Target.Address = Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 5).Address _
       And Target.Value <> "" _
       And Target.Value <> Sheets(1).Cells(Target.Row, 6).Value Then

Comment: Write `MsgBox Target.Value` before this line. What is on the MsgBox? Is it an error?

Comment: Yes it's an error msg. showing that value of 5 is not equal to 6

Comment: @ADRSAL - then try to capture the error and to avoid the if condition. See the update.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you're trying to do. but I tried your code and it's still giving me the same error

Comment: @ADRSAL - what is the value of `Target` when you enter the `Macro2` sub? I have added a `IsError` check, in case that it is a `!Div/0` error or similar.

Comment: ahh that's why. the value of F is #N/A before a value is inputted in column D. and it's giving the error before I input anything in D.

Comment: @ADRSAL - exactly. Errors cannot be compared and there is a need to 
"capture" them.

Comment: @ADRSAL - [consider marking the answer as accepted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) You can also mark an answer as accepted on this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532778/msgbox-for-a-range-of-cells